# Mysql select query with IF condition in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am writing a mysql query to find sum of two fields based on an id. I have tried writing query with IF condition in select query. Here is my query:

```
`SELECT (IF(`tax_rate_id`=2,SUM(`net_unit_price`*`quantity`),0)) AS sale5

    (IF(`tax_rate_id`=3,SUM(`net_unit_price`*`quantity`),0)) AS sale145

    FROM sma_sale_items

    where sale_id=4221`
```

I dont know whether my query is right.. If its not possible is there any other way to achieve this? Also I want to do the same query in codeigniter. Can anyone please help me..

Comment: are you getting improper grouping erorr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use conditional sum for the same something as

```
select
sum( case when tax_rate_id = 2 then net_unit_price*quantity else 0 end) as sale5,
sum( case when tax_rate_id = 3 then net_unit_price*quantity else 0 end) as sale145
from sma_sale_items
where sale_id=4221
```

Comment: your query works fine in mysql..but can you tell how it comes when written in codeigniter?

Comment: I am not an expert on `codeigniter`, however you can still run raw query in CI using `$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");` instead of query builder.

Comment: $query = $this->db->query("select
sum( case when tax_rate_id = 2 then net_unit_price*quantity else 0 end) as sale5,
sum( case when tax_rate_id = 3 then net_unit_price*quantity else 0 end) as sale145
from sma_sale_items
where sale_id=4221");

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Query

```
SELECT IF(`tax_rate_id`=2,
          SUM(`net_unit_price`*`quantity`),
          0) AS sale5,
       IF(`tax_rate_id`=3,
          SUM(`net_unit_price`*`quantity`),
          0) AS sale145 
FROM sma_sale_items 
WHERE sale_id=4221
```

You can use like this in codeigniter

```
 $this->db->select('IF(`tax_rate_id`=2,SUM(`net_unit_price`*`quantity`),0) AS sale5', FALSE);
    $this->db->select('IF(`tax_rate_id`=3,SUM(`net_unit_price`*`quantity`),0) AS sale145', FALSE);
    $this->db->from('sma_sale_items');
    $this->db->where(array('sale_id'=>4221));
    $result = $this->db->get();

    echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Comment: i tried like your query in codeigniter.. but it dont give any result.

Comment: check your last executed query ` echo $this->db->last_query();`